# cant access http://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench

Tags: tomcat, sesame

I am using sesame 2.5.0 and a newbie in using these triplestores. I had a problem that whenever I try to access http://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench using Google Chrome explorer it redirects to http://localhost:8080/openrdf-workbench/repositories/NONE/repositories and shows nothing.

Could you please guide me about the solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Does the problem only exist in Chrome, did you try another browser?

Comment: The same problem appears in Safari. [This should be a comment, but I don't have comment rights so far...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](http://www.openrdf.org/issues/browse/SES-823) with Sesame's Workbench application in Chrome, it seems to be a problem with how Chrome processes XML/XSL stylesheets.

Currently the only way around it is to use a different browser, such as Opera, Firefox, or Internet Explorer.